# Unable to click on class div SELENIUM

Tags: java, selenium, automation

I am unable to click on the element. I am able to locate it with xpath, the object with statements "element.getText()" returns correct values "element.isDisplayed()" returns true but when i say "element.click()" and it skip the action without click on it. Kindly advise on my mistake . Thanks you

CODE Button :

```
public static WebElement btn_AddDoubleBet(WebDriver driver) throws Exception{
        try{ 
             driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(70, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
             //element = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("html.js.flexbox.flexboxlegacy.canvas.canvastext.webgl.no-touch.geolocation.postmessage.no-websqldatabase.indexeddb.hashchange.history.draganddrop.websockets.rgba.hsla.multiplebgs.backgroundsize.borderimage.borderradius.boxshadow.textshadow.opacity.cssanimations.csscolumns.cssgradients.no-cssreflections.csstransforms.csstransforms3d.csstransitions.fontface.generatedcontent.video.audio.localstorage.sessionstorage.webworkers.applicationcache.svg.inlinesvg.smil.svgclippaths body div.wrap div#game.content.fr div.main.fl div#lottery.lottery div.count span.times span div.number-spin-btn.number-spin-btn-up"));
             element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[2]/div[4]/span[2]/span/div[2]"));
             Log.info("Increase Betting");
        }catch (Exception e){
            Log.error("Increase Betting is not found on the Confirmation Page");
            throw(e);
            }
        return element;
    }
```

Product Selection Code :

```
public static void BigSmallOddEven_Back_Execute(WebDriver driver)
            throws Exception {

        BigSmallOddEven_Page.btn_BigSmallOddEven(driver).click();

        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_AddDoubleBet(driver).click();
        }
        BigSmallOddEven_Page.pick_SelectedBigSmallOddEven(driver, 1).click();
        BigSmallOddEven_Page.pick_SelectedBigSmallOddEven(driver, 7).click();



        ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_ConfirmNumberToBet(driver).click();

        for (int k = 0; k < 49; k++) {
            ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_IncreaseBet(driver).click();
        }

        ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_ProceedBet(driver).click();

        ConfirmationPlaceBet_Page.btn_ConfirmBet(driver).click();
    }
```

HTML CODE :

```
<div class="number-spin-btn number-spin-btn-up" style="height: 21px"></div>
```

Comment: Is `element.click()` throwing any exception? if no exception is thrown then I am pretty sure the element is being clicked. How are you saying that the element is not being clicked? The HTML code is of the webelement you are trying to click? If you can post the link to the webpage if the page is accessible to all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the WebElement is being clicked. But WebElement being clicked is not the element you want.

From the HTML code you have given, try

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("div.number-spin-btn.number-spin-btn-up")).click();
```

If there are no other WebElements with same CSS selectors, then this should definitely click your WebElement.

You might also want to add some wait time within your for loop after clicking the element. As you need to give some time to the page to react to your input.